# Search in a timespan

Tags: python, search, timespan

I have this list with timestamps and I'd like to be able to search for all elements in a certain timespan (every timespan has corresponding information in another list) depending on the users input (hours <= 24 or days from midnight or neither).

Example (this is just an example list, the solution should work on very large lists)

```
list =  ['2002-03-31 19:30:41', '2002-03-31 19:30:41', '2002-03-31 19:43:49', '2002-03-31     19:43:50', '2002-03-31 19:50:05', '2002-03-31 19:50:06', '2002-03-31 19:50:06', '2002-03-31 19:50:44', '2002-03-31 19:50:45', '2002-03-31 19:50:45', '2002-03-31 19:51:50', '2002-03-31 19:51:50', '2002-03-31 19:51:50', '2002-03-31 19:52:25', '2002-03-31 19:52:25', '2002-03-31 19:52:25', '2002-03-31 19:53:05', '2002-03-31 19:53:06', '2002-03-31 19:53:06', '2002-03-31 19:53:06', '2002-03-31 19:53:17', '2002-03-31 19:54:14', '2002-03-31 19:54:14']
activity= [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w]
```

I'm going to use the last element `list[-1]` as a reference point. If the user wants to see activities during the past three hours witch means from `2002-03-31 16:54:14 to 2002-03-31 19:54:14` the positions of the timestamps are going to be used to get the activities from the other list. 
I thought first about converting every timestamp to something usable so its easier to compare each element but there must be an easier solution.

this [module](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) looks usable but I can't figure out how I could use it.

Best regards

Comment: How often will the user search this information? How large is the list of timestamps?

Comment: @MartijnPieters
Not very often, execution time is not important.
around 14000 timestamps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incredibly lucky in that your timestamps are in the easiest possible order for sorting, and you can punt on the whole "converting to a time value" and just do string comparisons:

```
times =  ['2002-03-31 19:30:41', '2002-03-31 19:30:41', '2002-03-31 19:43:49', '2002-03-31     19:43:50', '2002-03-31 19:50:05', '2002-03-31 19:50:06', '2002-03-31 19:50:06', '2002-03-31 19:50:44', '2002-03-31 19:50:45', '2002-03-31 19:50:45', '2002-03-31 19:51:50', '2002-03-31 19:51:50', '2002-03-31 19:51:50', '2002-03-31 19:52:25', '2002-03-31 19:52:25', '2002-03-31 19:52:25', '2002-03-31 19:53:05', '2002-03-31 19:53:06', '2002-03-31 19:53:06', '2002-03-31 19:53:06', '2002-03-31 19:53:17', '2002-03-31 19:54:14', '2002-03-31 19:54:14']
activity= ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w']

start = '2002-03-31 16:54:14'
end = '2002-03-31 19:54:14'

for time, activity in zip(times, activity):
    if time >= start and time <= end:
        print time, activity
```

Comment: Thanks!
How would I convert the users input that lets say is 13 days(from midnight) to start?

Comment: Look at the `datetime` module. You could pre-calculate the start date with something like `start = (datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=13)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00')`, then change your `if` statement to something like `if time >= start: ...`.

Answer (score 1):

As a workflow:

- Use the `datetime` module to transform your strings into `datetime` object with the `strptime` method: you get a list of `datetime` objects.
- Compute `timedeltas` by subtracting each entry of this list from the last one.
- You can use the `seconds` attribute of a `timedelta` to find out how many seconds between one point and the reference: compare that to `3*3600` (3h) to find out which items fall in the proper period.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
ls =  ['2002-03-31 19:30:41', '2002-03-31 19:30:41', '2002-03-31 19:43:49', '2002-03-31     19:43:50', '2002-03-31 19:50:05', '2002-03-31 19:50:06', '2002-03-31 19:50:06', '2002-03-31 19:50:44', '2002-03-31 19:50:45', '2002-03-31 19:50:45', '2002-03-31 19:51:50', '2002-03-31 19:51:50', '2002-03-31 19:51:50', '2002-03-31 19:52:25', '2002-03-31 19:52:25', '2002-03-31 19:52:25', '2002-03-31 19:53:05', '2002-03-31 19:53:06', '2002-03-31 19:53:06', '2002-03-31 19:53:06', '2002-03-31 19:53:17', '2002-03-31 19:54:14', '2002-03-31 19:54:14']

# target is one of the items in the list
target = datetime.strptime('2002-03-31 19:53:17', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
for l in ls:
    print datetime.strptime(l, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') - target
```

Prints

```
-1 day, 23:37:24
-1 day, 23:37:24
-1 day, 23:50:32
-1 day, 23:50:33
-1 day, 23:56:48
-1 day, 23:56:49
-1 day, 23:56:49
-1 day, 23:57:27
-1 day, 23:57:28
-1 day, 23:57:28
-1 day, 23:58:33
-1 day, 23:58:33
-1 day, 23:58:33
-1 day, 23:59:08
-1 day, 23:59:08
-1 day, 23:59:08
-1 day, 23:59:48
-1 day, 23:59:49
-1 day, 23:59:49
-1 day, 23:59:49
0:00:00
0:00:57
0:00:57
```

The `datetime.strptime(l, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') - target` returns a `timedelta` object ([docs](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html?highlight=timedelta#timedelta-objects)). You can access the `timedelta` objects `days`, `seconds` and `microseconds` attributes and compare those to some desired time span. For instance to get all the index of all the events that occured less than an hour from some reference point:

```
less_than_an_hour = []
for i,l in enumerate(ls):
    if (datetime.strptime(l, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') - target).seconds < 3600:
        less_than_an_hour.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd:

- convert the list of timestamps to `datetime` objects:

  ```
  times = [datetime.datetime.strptime(t, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for t in times]
  ```
- Use the [`bisect` module](http://docs.python.org/library/bisect.html) to find your start time the user requested. Using `bisect` is a much faster method than using linear search, provided you translate the user input to `datetime` objects as well:

  ```
  start = datetime.datetime(2002, 3, 31, 19, 53, 17)
  startindex = bisect.bisect_left(times, start)
  ```
- Use [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) functions to merge the two lists into one that shows entries that match your range:

  ```
  end = datetime.datetime(2002, 4, 1, 07, 53, 17)

  merged = itertools.izip(times, activity)
  fromstart = itertools.islice(merged, startindex)
  untilend = itertools.takewhile(lambda e: e[0] <= end, fromstart)
  ```

The `untilend` iterable now generates entries between `start` and `end` as `(time, activity)` tuples, without using any extra memory for copied lists. This let's you handle huge amounts of data efficiently.

Demo:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> import datetime
>>> import bisect
>>> times =  ['2002-03-31 19:30:41', '2002-03-31 19:30:41', '2002-03-31 19:43:49', '2002-03-31     19:43:50', '2002-03-31 19:50:05', '2002-03-31 19:50:06', '2002-03-31 19:50:06', '2002-03-31 19:50:44', '2002-03-31 19:50:45', '2002-03-31 19:50:45', '2002-03-31 19:51:50', '2002-03-31 19:51:50', '2002-03-31 19:51:50', '2002-03-31 19:52:25', '2002-03-31 19:52:25', '2002-03-31 19:52:25', '2002-03-31 19:53:05', '2002-03-31 19:53:06', '2002-03-31 19:53:06', '2002-03-31 19:53:06', '2002-03-31 19:53:17', '2002-03-31 19:54:14', '2002-03-31 19:54:14']
>>> activity= ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w']
>>> times = [datetime.datetime.strptime(t, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for t in times]
>>> start = datetime.datetime(2002, 3, 31, 19, 53, 17)
>>> end = datetime.datetime(2002, 4, 1, 07, 53, 17)
>>> startindex = bisect.bisect_left(times, start)
>>> merged = itertools.izip(times, activity)
>>> fromstart = itertools.islice(merged, startindex)
>>> untilend = itertools.takewhile(lambda e: e[0] <= end, fromstart)
>>> for time, activity in untilend:
...     print time, activity
... 
2002-03-31 19:30:41 a
2002-03-31 19:30:41 b
2002-03-31 19:43:49 c
2002-03-31 19:43:50 d
2002-03-31 19:50:05 e
2002-03-31 19:50:06 f
2002-03-31 19:50:06 g
2002-03-31 19:50:44 h
2002-03-31 19:50:45 i
2002-03-31 19:50:45 j
2002-03-31 19:51:50 k
2002-03-31 19:51:50 l
2002-03-31 19:51:50 m
2002-03-31 19:52:25 n
2002-03-31 19:52:25 o
2002-03-31 19:52:25 p
2002-03-31 19:53:05 q
2002-03-31 19:53:06 r
2002-03-31 19:53:06 s
2002-03-31 19:53:06 t
```